# Save Data in mysql using two tables in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview, combobox, textbox, mysql-workbench

I have my Codes here, the first table(tblreg) that data to be inserted, I used only textbox and combobox to retrieve to save on my First table database. The second table(tblsisterbrother) is I used DataGridview to insert the data on my Second table database.

My Problem is when I click save, all the data are saved on my database in correct tables, but it has an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. And my if-else statement in result does not display the appropriate Messagebox, or it does not display after the error.

```
Private Sub cmdRegister_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegister.Click

 con.ConnectionString = ("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=12345;database=dbsis3bkenth")
Try
                con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblreg (IDNo, LName, FName, MI, NName, Course, Yr, Div1, Gender, Age, Hght, Wght, DOB, POB, Religion, Address, Tel, AddWSudying, Scholarship, NFather, OccFather, AIncome, AgencyFather, NMother, OccMother, AgencyMother, PNEmergency, PNEAddress, Relation, PNETel, Hobbies, WEmploy, Elem, YTElem, Secondary, YTSecondary, College, YTCollege) " & _
                                "VALUES ('" & vcbIDNo & "','" & vtxtLName & "','" & vtxtFName & "','" & vtxtMI & "','" & vcbNName & "','" & vcbCourse & "','" & vcbYr & "','" & vcbDiv & "','" & vcbGender & "','" & vtxtAge & "','" & vtxtHght & "','" & vtxtWght & "','" & vdtpDOB & "','" & vtxtPOB & "','" & vcbReligion & "','" & vtxtAddress & "','" & vtxtTel & "','" & vtxtAddWSudying & "','" & vcbScholarship & "','" & vtxtNFather & "','" & vtxtOccFather & "','" & vtxtAIncome & "','" & vtxtAgencyFather & "','" & vtxtNMother & "','" & vtxtOccMother & "','" & vtxtAgencyMother & "','" & vtxtPNEmergency & "','" & vtxtPNEAddress & "','" & vtxtRelation & "','" & vtxtPNETel & "','" & vtxtHobbies & "','" & vtxtWEmploy & "','" & vtxtElem & "','" & vtxtYTElem & "','" & vtxtSecondary & "','" & vtxtYTSecondary & "','" & vtxtCollege & "','" & vtxtYTCollege & "');"
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblsisterbrother (LName, FName, MI,IDNoBrodSis) " & _
                                    "VALUES ('" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("LN").Value.ToString & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("FN").Value.ToString & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("MI").Value.ToString & "','" & vcbIDNo & "');"
                    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                Next

                If result = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Data has been Inserted!")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Successfully saved!")

                End If
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
```